# if else statement incorrect output

Tags: bash

I'm working on a custom Nagios script that will monitor cPanel to make sure it is running and give back a status depending on what it gets from an output of service cpanel status. This is what I have:

```
##############################################################################
#   Constants

cpanelstate="running..."

ALERT_OK="OK - cPanel is running"
ALERT_CRITICAL="CRITICAL - cPanel is NOT running"
###############################################################################

cpanel=$(service cpanel status | head -1)

if [ "$cpanel" = "$cpanelstate" ]; then

        echo $ALERT_OK
        exit 0
else
        echo $ALERT_CRITICAL
        exit 2

fi

exit $exitstatus
```

When I run the script, this is the output I get:

```
root@shared01 [/home/mvelez]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_cpanel 
CRITICAL - cPanel is NOT running
```

When I run the script, cPanel IS RUNNING but this is the output I get. As a matter of fact, no matter what the status reports for cPanel this is the output that comes out. When I comment out the ELSE, ECHO and EXIT 2 statement:

```
#else
#       echo $ALERT_CRITICAL
#       exit 2
```

It gives back a blank output:

```
root@shared01 [/home/mvelez]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_cpanel 
root@shared01 [/home/mvelez]#
```

I'm not sure what I'm not doing correctly as I am very new to bash scripting and trying to learn as I go along. Thank you in advanced for any and all help very very much!

Comment: From your question, it looks like you missed some basic debugging steps; for example, you don't indicate what the actual value of `$cpanel` *is*, which suggests that maybe you didn't try printing it out to see?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I thought that the output of that statement would be sent to the if statement. 

If I add the echo command to print out the string, how can I then throw it in the if statement so it can be processed and give the correct end output?

Comment: What shell is executing your script? What's your script's shebang line (`#!/bin/....`)? If there is none, what is your shell? What does `service cpanel status` return _interactively_? Does it perhaps report to _stderr_ (though you should have seen stderr output when you ran your script)?

Comment: It's supposed to be #!/bin/bash but even when I add that it still does not work correctly.

The output when I run service cpanel status is the following:

root@shared01 [/home/mvelez]# service cpanel status
cpsrvd (pid  10066) is running...
entropychat is stopped
stunnel is stopped
qrunner is stopped

Comment: If `service cpanel status` prints to _stderr_ (again, that's not consistent with what you report, but worth a shot), try `cpanel=$(service cpanel status 2>&1 | head -1)`; also, add `set -xv` after the shebang line to see what your script is doing at runtime.

Comment: @mklement0, I did what you said and this is what I got:

Everything had a + that was in the script but for the if statement it didnt as if it skips it: http://pastebin.com/aSxapSQu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work, but you might need to run it with sudo, because 'service' might not be available for ordinary users.

```
#!/bin/bash

##############################################################################
#   Constants

cpanelstate="running"

ALERT_OK="OK - cPanel is running"
ALERT_CRITICAL="CRITICAL - cPanel is NOT running"
###############################################################################

cpanel=$(service apache2 status | head -1)
echo CPANEL $cpanel
if [[ $cpanel == *$cpanelstate* ]]; then

        echo $ALERT_OK
        exit 0
else
        echo $ALERT_CRITICAL
        exit 2

fi
```

Comment: Yes this worked! This is the output I got:

    root@shared01 [/home/mvelez]#
    /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_cpanel 
    CPANEL cpsrvd (pid 10066) is running...
    OK - cPanel is running

I stopped it and ran it again and this is what I got:

    root@shared01 [/home/mvelez]#
    /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_cpanel 
    CPANEL cpsrvd is stopped
    OK - cPanel is running

It's supposed to kick out a CRITICAL - cPanel is not running but it didn't.

Comment: It looks like my 'service' command has a different output compare to yours. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: I've just updated the answer to include your specifics. Check it out.

Comment: +1, but please don't revert to legacy syntax for command substitution (`\`...\`` vs. `$(...)`).

Comment: my apologies, I'm an old school, will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[@Oleg Gryb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24356721/45375) solves your problem, but as for why your original script didn't work:

`[ "$cpanel" = "$cpanelstate" ]` compared the *full* command output - e.g., `cpsrvd (pid  10066) is running...`, against a *substring* of the expected output, `running...` for *equality*, which will obviously fail.

The solution is to use `bash`'s pattern matching, provided via the right-hand side of its `[[ ... ]]` conditional (bash's superior alternative to the `[ ... ]` conditional):

`[[ "$cpanel" == *"$cpanelstate" ]]`

`*` represents any sequence of characters, so that this conditional returns true, if `$cpanel` *ends with* `$cpanelstate` (note how `*` must be unquoted to be recognized as a special pattern char.)

Comment: @Oleg Gryb Yes the above changes corrected the issue and it is now working! Thank you for your help and explanations. This helped me understand what I was doing wrong and how to do this correctly! This will help me learn how do to this again and use it in other instances also. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @user3765678: I'm glad to hear it; you're welcome. For the benefit of answerers and future readers: If an answer _solved_ your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark next to it; if you found it at least _helpful_, please up-vote it by clicking the up-arrow icon.